# Kdenlive: Speed up the audio and video without losing pitch

Tags: 18.04, sound, video, video-editor, kdenlive

I am using Kdenlive Version 17.12.3 in Ubuntu 18.04. I have increased the  the speed of the video and it resulted in the pitch variation of audio. Is there any way to change the pitch? I even tried changing the speed and pitch of the audio outside using Audacity but no matter how hard I tried I couldn't match the length of the audio and video after that.

Comment: Test Rubberband Pitch effect at 0.900

Answer (score 8):

With Kdenlive 20.08, you can right-click the clip in the timeline -> Change Speed. In the dialog choose the speed ratio, and check `Pitch compensation`.

[image: Change Speed Dialog]

Comment: You have to install `rubberband` to make `Pitch compensation` active. It is greyed out in Kdenlive, which is a bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421257

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I have found a way to do it right inside Kdenlive. Let's assume you speed the video up to 110% its original speed, or 1.1. Then you can add a pitch scaler with a pitch shift of 1/1.1 = 0.909, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI0AU.png). This works for a wide range of speed increases. I used the effect "AM pitchshifter", but any pitch shifter should work.

Answer (score 0):

With Kdenlive Version 19.12.3
First do a pitch shift (audio effects => AM pitchshifter) second Change the Speed of the clip and that is the solution!

Thanks to [157 239n](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239299/1254185)

`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As the friend said, you need to install `rubberband`. I did this and Kdenlive pitch compensation worked.